# Filtering a list of arrays f#

Tags: list, filter, f#

sorry if the questions to basic, but i havent been able to do this for some time.  I have created a lists of lists in which the second array contains  a parameter that can be either an f or a p.  I need to create two new lists of arrays, one containing the items that have the f parameter and the other one containing the p parameter.

edit: trying to explain myself:

I have a list containing a series of facebook publications, and each one of this publications has information, such as what type of publication it is.. they can be either a p (text) or f (picture).  What i need to do is to create two separate lists of this publications by the type publication they are.

example of data: [[|"publication0ID", "Poster0ID","TypeofPublication0"|];[|"publication1ID", "Poster1ID","TypeofPublication1"|]]

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "the second list contains a parameter". Can you elaborate please? And you might want to take a look at the [List.partition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353782.aspx) function, it might be just what you want.

Comment: When you say "contains a parameter that can be either an f or a p", does that mean that the second list is a list of tuples? Please tell what the type of your list of lists is.

Comment: If you can give a sample of your data structure rather than attempt to describe it, that would make your question clearer.

Comment: Sure alex, ill give a sample [["publication0ID", "Poster0ID","TypeofPublication0"..];["publication1ID", "Poster1ID","TypeofPublication1"..]...]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = [[|"publication0ID"; "Poster0ID"; "f"|];[|"publication1ID"; "Poster1ID"; "p"|]]


let texts, pictures =
    data
    |> List.partition (List.ofArray >> function
        | _ :: _ :: "f" :: _ -> true 
        | _ :: _ :: "p" :: _ -> false 
        | _ -> failwith "neither f nor p"
    )
```

This will split the lists according to the third "parameter", which you called "TypeOfPublication".

I changed your sample code, because your sub-arrays <del>sub-lists</del> contain only one tuple and judging by your "..." I tought that might be wrong.

**To explain:**

[List.partition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353782.aspx) splits a list according to a function that is called for every element in the list. When the function returns true, the element will be put into the first list of the result tuple, and into the second list when false.

Since your elements are arrays <del>also lists</del>, it will be checked if the third element in the array <del>list</del> is either "f", which will cause the array <del>list</del> to be put in the `texts` result, and "p", which will be put into `pictures`.

If the third element is neither "f" nor "p", an exception will be thrown.

---

Update for the comment:

If your sub-arrays are always exactly three elements long, you can use this version:

```
let texts, pictures =
    data
    |> List.partition (function
        | [| _; _; "f" |] -> true
        | [| _; _; "p" |] -> false
        | _ -> failwith "neither f nor p or wrong array length"
    )
```

Or, you can use the first version and just put `List.ofArray >>` in between the function keyword and the opening paren so that it reads: `List.partition (List.ofArray >> function` (I updated the code above as well).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems i made a serious mistake, i seem to have a list of arrays, cause i am getting the following message as i try to use your code "this expresion was expected to have a type string [] but has a type list". furthermore, when i printed in the array in the console i got [[|"publication0ID"; "Poster0ID"; "TypeofPublication0"|];[|"publication1ID"; "Poster1ID"; "TypeofPublication1"|]].  sorry for all of the mistakes..

Comment: Thnks! it worked perfectly, thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your main list is of type `(int, string) list list`, then if you

```
let f = 1
let p = 1
```

you should be able to filter your `main_list` by using

```
let f_items = seq {
    let! sub_list = main_list
    let! (selector, item) = sub_list
    if selector == f then
        yield item
}
```

and likewise, to get the "p" items, you would use `selector == p`.

I had to bring out my F# book to be able to write this code, I haven't used F# for so long! I don't have F# on this computer, so I don't know if the above code actually works.